# Problemas para generar un .exe desde un scrip .py con pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.8, pyside2

Hola tengo una aplicación desarrollada para leer datos por http con la Liberia request, tiene un entorno visual con la librería QT y Pyside2. También utilizo la librería Pandas y Numpy. Además usó las librerías time y datetime para manejar las fecha. Utilizó la librería la librería matplotlib para realizar un gráfico. Y por ultimo utilizo la librería argparse y configparser para que lea un archivo de configuración
Todo funciona bien en python 3.8. Pero lo quiero pasar a un archivo .exe, utilice pyinstaller y me lo genero bien pero cuando quiero ejecutar el archivo .exe me da el siguiente error

para generar el exe uso la siguiente instruccion pyinstaller --onedir --windowed --CalibNetlog.py

Estas son las librerías que utilizo.

sys, requests, datetime, time, argparse, pandas,  configparser , matplotlib.pyplot, numpy

Si lo ejecuto por CMD me da el siguiente mensaje:

```
    c:\users\lucas\pycharmprojects\netlog calibrador\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:493: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Matplotlib installs where the data is not in the mpl-data subdirectory of the package are deprecated since 3.2 and support for them will be removed two minor releases later.
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CalibNetlog.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\lucas\pycharmprojects\netlog calibrador\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 898, in <module>
  File "matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 480, in _get_data_path
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 239, in wrapper
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 534, in get_data_path
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 239, in wrapper
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 563, in _get_data_path
NameError: name 'defaultParams' is not defined
[8148] Failed to execute script CalibNetlog
```

Comment: Hola aun tienes el problema o ya lo resolviste?